# Provisioning profile error persists

Tags: iphone, xcode

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

I have the above error message when trying to compile to an iPhone 5 for testing.  The project has been compiled to an iPhone 4 (with iOS 6) and an iPhone 4s (with iOS 5) and it is ok.

Have also downloaded a file called "iOS_development.cer" from the Apple developer site.  Not sure if the *.cer file is the right file to download.  And also cannot install the *.cer file in Xcode.

Please help ...

Comment: pls make sure your iPhone 5 UDID added into that provision profile or not?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, will check the UDID again.

Comment: can you post some screen shots?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "`.cer`" file is a certificate file that allows you to code sign apps that you install and/or distribute ADHOC versions for.

The file you really want to have is the mobile provisioning file.  If you download it from the provisioning portal, it will have a "`.mobileprovision`" extension at the end of it.  Double clicking this file will install it into your Xcode organizer (under "Devices").

If you did it correctly, it should appear on this screen:

[image: Provisioning Profiles in the Organizer]

You install the certificate once, and you might create a mobile provision file for each new project / app you work on (unless you have Xcode manage the provisioning automatically).

Comment: Under "Devices" in iOS Provisioning Portal, there is a list of devices that I have used including the iPhone 5.  There are 2 buttons at the top of the web page, "Upload Devices" and "Add Devices". But there doesn't seem to have anything to download.

Comment: When I click on "Provisioning Profiles" under LIBRARY at the top, there are a list of Profiles including one that I have just downloaded and double clicked.  But under iPhone 5, the "Provisioning Profiles" is empty.

Comment: When I try to drag the newly downloaded Provisioning Profile to the iPhone 5 empty list, a warning box comes up with "1 profile cannot be installed .... and "iPhone 5 is not included in this ...".

Comment: Now the phone can be used after the "Refresh" icon on the lower right of the "Organizer - Devices" screen is clicked. Thanks for your kind assistance ...